# Need to know to code printer name in Java

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I have use jasper report to create a report in Java and most of the time i tried to setup the printer name by using code, but I couldn't do that. Please help me how to give printer name to print without using print manager

```
try {
        String comname = "";
        comname = "Stars Bombay Sweet (Pvt) Ltd.";

        JRTableModelDataSource dts = new JRTableModelDataSource(jTable1.getModel());
        String path = "D:\\Aster Soft\\Stars Reports\\posh_print\\report1.jrxml";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put("name", comname);

        params.put("para1", InvNo.getText());
        params.put("para2", dat);
        params.put("para3", Customer.getText());
        params.put("credit", jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());

        params.put("Qty", GrossQty.getText());
        params.put("TotAmont", TotalAmount.getText());
        params.put("Discount", Discount.getText());
        params.put("GrossAmont", DisAmount.getText());

        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dts);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(print, false);
        JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.class.getResource("/classpath/yourReport.jasper").getPath(),
            new HashMap(), new yourReportDataSource());
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Create an array of PrintServices */
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        int selectedService = 0;
        /* Scan found services to see if anyone suits our needs */
        for(int i = 0; i &lt; services.length;i++){
        if(services[i].getName().toUpperCase().contains("Your printer's name")){
        /*If the service is named as what we are querying we select it */
         selectedService = i;
         }
        }
        job.setPrintService(services[selectedService]);
```

I think below blog link will help you

http://blog.marcnuri.com/choosing-a-printer-programmatically-in-jasper-reports/